# Creating an object with a subset of properties and their values from another object

Tags: c#, object, dynamicobject

Consider the following class -

```cs
public class User
{
    [Selected]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Selected]
    public int Code { get; set; }
    
    public object GetValue()
    {
        // need to do something here
    }
}
```

`[Selected]` here is nothing but a marker attribute. I want `GetValue` method to return an object which will have the `[Selected]`-marked properties with corresponding values. That is, in the code below -

```cs
private static void Execute()
{
    User user = new User
    {
        Name = "alice",
        Email = "alice@liddell.com",
        Password = "123456",
        Code = 1234
    };

    var value = user.GetValue();
}
```

`value` should be an object with two properties `Name` and `Code` which should have the values `"alice"` and `1234` respectively.

After some searching I tried `ExpandoObject` (which I never used before) -

```cs
public object GetValue()
{
    var dictionary = this.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(Selected), false) != null).ToDictionary(p => p.Name);
    dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
    foreach (var item in dictionary)
    {
        object value = item.Value.GetValue(this);
        ((IDictionary<string, object>)expando).Add(item.Key, value);
    }
    return expando;
}
```

But it didn't serve my purpose - the client/consumer of `value` object somehow couldn't read/access the property values.

Any suggestions?

**Edit :**
There might be a lot of classes like `User` and the `GetValue` method will be called from within a generic method. So, at runtime I have no way to know what type the object is and which properties are marked.

Comment: Since you already know which properties you want at compile time, I'd ditch the attribute and make a different class with the properties you want. e.g. `UserLite`.

Comment: @itsme86, actually at runtime I wouldn't know. There will be a lot of classes, and `GetValue` will be called from within a generic method. I'll update the post to make it clear.

Comment: _might be a lot of classes_ - This means that it is impossible to predict types and properties in advance. This means that you must to use a dynamic data structure like a dictionary. POCO is not possible in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

To access the fields by name it is easier to cast the returned object to IDictionary:

```
    var value = (IDictionary<string, object>) user.GetValue();
    Console.WriteLine(value["Name"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplify your method to this:

```
public Dictionary<string, object> GetValue()
{
    var dictionary = this.GetType()
        .GetProperties()
        .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(Selected), false) != null)
        .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.GetValue(this));

    return dictionary;
}
```

Use:

```
var value = user.GetValue(); // value is Dictionary

foreach (var kvp in value)
{
    Console.WriteLine(kvp);
}
```

---

If you wish POCO, then you can do it like follows

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }

    public SelectedUserProperties GetValue()
    {
        return new SelectedUserProperties
        {
            Name = Name,
            Code = Code
        };
    }
}

public class SelectedUserProperties
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }
}
```

It is assumed that the selected properties are known in advance, before compilation.
This makes the marker attribute unnecessary and can be completely removed.

Comment: I'm expecting a poco type object to access the properties directly, not a Dictionary

Comment: Since the shape of the objects would be defined at runtime, I'm sure `poco` was a bad choice of term on my part. Sorry :(  I'd better make the Dictionary work for me, than creating all those classes statically. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

What you did works well, you just have to use the keyword [dynamic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic) when you call the method `GetValue`.

```
    dynamic value = user.GetValue();
```

If you are using **var**, `value` will be of the same type as the return type of your function (i.e `object`) at compile time. Therefore, if you try to do `value.Name` your compiler won't allow it because the class `Object` doesn't have any attribute `Name`.

**dynamic** tells your program to do the type checking at runtime.

Comment: What if I just return the value directly to the consumer?